# Table structured data in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am building an application for ordering coffee. On one of the routes I have the store menu, which has a series of drinks with attributes of type, size, price. So for example a 12oz Mocha could cost $5.00.

I'm having trouble structuring this data and displaying it how I'm thinking, maybe I'm not thinking in an "ember way" as I'm new to ember and frontend development in general.

In my route I've tried a couple different things. I have a 'store-drink' model which returns all the drinks for the store. I've tried using that as my model and am able to return all the store drinks in my model, but it's difficult to display all the drinks in a table like format since there's no built-in helper like `{{if drink.type == 'Mocha'}}`.

The other thing I've tried is using Ember.RSVP.hash to separate the drinks in the route, and then in my template install [Ember Truth Helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) to determine the size of each drink.

```
// routes/menu.js
model: function() {
  // get the drinks for the current store, for now hardcode
  const storeId = 4;

  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    mochas: this.store.find(
      'store-drink', {'store':storeId, 'type':'Mocha'}),
    espressos: this.store.find(
      'store-drink', {'store':storeId, 'type':'Espesso'}),
  })
},
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set('mochas', model.mochas);
  controller.set('espressos', model.espressos);
}

//menu.hbs
{{#each drink in mochas}}
  {{if (eq drink.type 'Mocha')}}
    <h2>mochas</h2>
    {{drink.type}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Not only am I getting all the drinks returned in my 'mochas' object in the controller, but I can't seem to get the the installed if helper to work either.

Any suggestions? Maybe I should have a whole different approach or maybe I'm just missing something.

I'm on ember 1.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used ember-truth-helper, but looking at the docs shouldn't it be:

```
{{#each drink in mochas}}
  {{#if (eq drink.type 'Mocha'}}}
    <h2>mochas</h2>
    {{drink.type}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Also you wrote `{{item.type}}` instead of `{{drink.type}}`. Though now that you've sub-queried the mocha drinks you should be able to just get rid off the `if`. Leaving just:

```
{{#each drink in mochas}}
  <h2>mochas</h2>
  {{drink.type}}
{{/each}}
```

For `find` it simply sends a GET to the backend, which is responsible for what is returned. If you want to filter in place do:

```
this.store.find('store-drink', {'store':storeId}, function(drink) {
  return drink.type === 'Mocha';
});
```

Comment: hey sorry i made a mistake in copying code - was in the middle of changes. Actually it's `{{if (eq drink.type 'Mocha')}}` according to the docs but I'm getting a build error saying that the blocks don't match

Comment: @awwester You need the `#`.

Comment: ok, thanks I have the template part working and understand better the difference between helpers with # and without #. Any idea why my mochas object is not returning just the drinks with type mocha? I want the route to filter the drinks by type, but for some reason my mochas object is returning all drink types.

Comment: @awwester `find` relies on the backend for filtering.

Comment: @awwester I've added an example for filtering on the frontend.

Comment: that makes sense, I only have filtering on my backend set up for store and not type, thank you!